# Spring Boot Aspect Autowiring

Tags: spring-boot, autowired, spring-aop

I have created an annotation to invoke a Spring AOP Aspect in a spring boot project. All works fine until I try to autowire a dependency into the Aspect: the autowiring doesn't happen.

I have read in various questions in stackoverflow that this is because the Aspect is not Spring managed. Apologies if this has been answered previously, but I have I have tried various solutions mentioned in stackoverflow including using @Configurable and implementing ApplicationContextAware.

What is the simplest change to make to get this to work?

I have created a simple example to illustrate the problem: the test passes if the dependency is created directly:

```
/**
 * Aspect applying the annotation {@link LogDuration} to where ever it has been added, see {@link #logDuration(ProceedingJoinPoint, LogDuration)}.  
 */
@Configurable
@Aspect
public class LogDurationAspect {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger( LogDurationAspect.class );

    @Autowired
    private TimeMeasurer timeMeasurer;// = new TimeMeasurer();

    public LogDurationAspect() {
    }

    /** For any method with @LogDuration, no matter what the return type, name, or arguments are, call this method to log how long it takes. */ 
    @Around("@annotation(annotation)")
    public Object logDuration( ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint , LogDuration annotation ) throws Throwable {

        System.out.println( timeMeasurer );

        final long startTime = timeMeasurer.now();
        try{
            final Object result = joinPoint.proceed();

            final long duration = timeMeasurer.timeSince( startTime );

            LOGGER.info( String.format( "%s returned %s took %d ms %.3f s" , annotation.value() , result , duration , 0.001 * duration ) );

            return result;
        }
        catch ( Throwable t){
            final long duration = timeMeasurer.timeSince( startTime );
            LOGGER.error( String.format( "%s took %d ms %.3f s" , annotation.value() , duration , 0.001 * duration ) , t);
            throw t;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Simple annotation which will log the duration of a method via {@link LogDurationAspect#logDuration(org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint, LogDuration)}.
 */
@Retention(java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface LogDuration {
   String value();
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = LogDurationAspectITests.TestConfiguration.class )
public class LogDurationAspectITests {

    @Autowired
    private TestListener underTest;

    @Rule 
    public OutputCapture outputCapture = new OutputCapture();

    @Autowired
    private TimeMeasurer timeMeasurer;

    @Test 
    public void annotationWorks() {

        // prove that scanning is working
        assertThat( timeMeasurer , is( notNullValue( ) ) );

        underTest.doIt( 1234 );

        assertThat( outputCapture.toString() , containsString ( "doIt 1 2 3 returned 2468 took") );
    }

    @SpringBootApplication
    @Configuration
    public static class TestConfiguration {
    }
}

@Component
public class TimeMeasurer{

    /** @return milliseconds between now and start.*/ 
    public long timeSince( long start ) {

        return now( ) - start;        
    }

    /** @return current time in milliseconds. */
    public long now( ) {

        return System.currentTimeMillis( );
    }

}

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

And how to debug the aspect?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Added a bean to the configuration class that uses Aspects.aspectOf

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public static class TestConfiguration {

    /** 
     * This is needed to get hold of the instance of the aspect which is created outside of the spring container, 
     * and make it available for autowiring. 
     */
    @Bean
    LogDurationAspect logDurationAspect()
    {
        final LogDurationAspect aspect = Aspects.aspectOf(LogDurationAspect.class);
        return aspect;
    }
}
```